# Display the element appearing at even and odd subscript position separately in an array element in C programming

Tags: c

The question is:
Write a program that will read an array of integers. The program should display the elements appearing at even and odd subscript position separately.
This is program from the book but I don't understand that why this program output like this way. Instead to print out odd number at odd position and even number at even position, the output here is totally different.
'''

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int even,odd,i,n,a[50];
    printf("Enter the number of terms: ");
    scanf("%d",&n); //input
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter number %d:",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    printf("\nOdd\tEven\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
       /*if(a[i]%2!=0) */  
        if(i%2!=0) //array index starts from 0.
        printf("\n%d\t",a[i]);
         else 
           printf("%d\t",a[i]);
        }
     return 0;
}
```

[image: The expected answer]

[image]

Comment: The code is simply wrong. It does not correctly align the output to the headings even though it does correctly differentiate between the odd and even indicies. Run the program in a debugger and watch what it is doing and what the output is for each line of code.

Comment: Please edit your question (using the `edit` button just below the tags) and include the output you expect from your input. Thanks.

Comment: I am under the impression that the accepted answer really doesn't do what the OP originally wanted to achieve, you should try it with e.g. input 2 - 4 - 8 - 6- 7 - 5 to confirm and make sure it really is what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

I formatted the output like this:

```
printf("%5s%5s\n", "Odd", "Even");
for(i=0;i<n;++i)
{
    printf(i%2?"%5d\n" : "%5d" , a[i]);
}
return 0;
```

And the result is:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4844KB
  Odd Even
    2    3
    4    5
    6    7
```

Comment: You might want to double-check your output. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yo!

You print numbers using :

```
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
   /*if(a[i]%2!=0) */  
    if(i%2!=0) //array index starts from 0.
    printf("\n%d\t",a[i]);
     else 
       printf("%d\t",a[i]);
    }
```

There are a few reasons why it's wrong, first :
At line 16 (3 in my segment), you replaced a condition on the **value in the array** with a condition on the **index in the array**, which means that regardless of the numbers you input, the output will always have the same form :

```
(with nX the Xth number you input)
n1
n2 n3
n4 n5
...
nn
```

Then, even solving that issue, you'd end up with the first number always being printed on the left anyway, and the fix depends on your desired output.

For :

```
Odd Even
    2
3
    4
5
    6
```

You could simply replace `printf("%d\t",a[i]);` with  `printf("\n\t%d",a[i]);`

However, for

```
Odd Even
    2
3   4
5   6
```

You'll need to keep track of whether or not an odd number has been printed last or not, and act accordingly, which you can figure out how to do by yourself.

Have fun learning.

**EDIT: OP provided expected format, updating my answer accordingly:**

For:

```
Odd Even
3   2
5   4
    6
```

You could either keep two indices to keep track of what you want to print, and search for the next odd or next even number respectively or reorder the numbers to fit the format. Either way you need to handle having more of a type, which is done in the first case by handling line-breaks separately from numbers, which give you code similar to :

```
 for(o=0, e=0; o < n || e < n;) {
    // Skip all even numbers and print next odd one, if any
    while (o < n && a[o] % 2 == 0) 
        ++o;
    if (o < n)
        printf("%d", a[o]);
    // Skip all odd numbers and print next even one, if any
    while (e < n && a[e] % 2 != 0)
        ++e;
    if (e < n)
        printf("\t%d", a[e]);
    printf("\n");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to print even and odd array subscript value column-wise where the odd subscript value should print before the even subscript value. That means, `i + 1`<sup>th</sup> subscript value should print before the `i`<sup>th</sup> subscript value (provided both `i` and `i + 1` subscripts are valid i.e. within size of array). Few points:

- The number of lines in output will be `half` the size of array, if the size of array will be even, otherwise it will be `half + 1` the size of array, if size of array is odd.
- A case need to be consider that if the size of array is odd then the last line of output should only print the even value and odd column should be left blank.

Implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARR_SZ 50

int main(void) {
    int n, a[ARR_SZ];

    printf("Enter the number of terms: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    // Add input validation code.
    // Below code based on assumption that 
    // input is valid i.e. 0 <= n <= ARR_SZ.

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("Enter number %d:", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    int count = n % 2 ? n/2 + 1 : n/2;
    int i = 0;

    printf("\nOdd\tEven\n");
    while (count--) {
        if (i + 1 < n) {
            printf ("%d", a[i + 1]);
        }
        printf ("\t%d\n", a[i]);
        i = i + 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
Enter the number of terms: 6
Enter number 1:2
Enter number 2:3
Enter number 3:4
Enter number 4:5
Enter number 5:6
Enter number 6:7

Odd Even
3   2
5   4
7   6

# ./a.out
Enter the number of terms: 1
Enter number 1:5

Odd Even
    5

# ./a.out
Enter the number of terms: 3
Enter number 1:7
Enter number 2:6 
Enter number 3:5

Odd Even
6   7
    5
```